# vue.js matching array method

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, for-loop

so i'm trying to fill my form with myproduct's value where the id_product == input.But when i run the code,the value is not return.What's wrong with my code

```
this.products.forEach(i => {
       if(this.products[i].id == item.id_product)
        {
            
            this.form.product_name = this.products[i].product_name;
            
            this.form.id_category = this.products[i].id_category;
            this.form.description = this.products[i].description;
            this.form.price = this.products[i].price;
            this.form.color = this.products[i].color;
            this.form.size = this.products[i].size;
            this.form.stock = this.products[i].stock;
            this.form.weight = this.products[i].weight;
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First parameter of the callback for [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is the current value, not index. Second parameter(optional) is index, so either pass the current value only like `.forEach(product => {...})` or with index like `.forEach((product, i) => {...})`

```
this.products.forEach(product => {
       if(product.id == item.id_product)
        {
            
            this.form.product_name = product.product_name;
            
            this.form.id_category = product.id_category;
            this.form.description = product.description;
            this.form.price = product.price;
            this.form.color = product.color;
            this.form.size = product.size;
            this.form.stock = product.stock;
            this.form.weight = product.weight;
        } 
    });
```